# How to make dynamic column selection within displayed dataframe/table in streamlit?

Tags: python, dataframe, streamlit

I want to be able to select columns/ column names from within displayed table in streamlit, currently it only reorders the data when clicked.The selected column names [without data] should be returned.

I understand that i can use something like st.multiselect, where i pass the first row as input and can select values from this row, but this selection is separate i just want this function within the table itself.

Is there a way i can enable something like column selection in st.write/st.dataframe?

Comment: This is not supported. Could you tell us why you are doing this?
Could you tell more about "but this selection is separate i just want this function within the table itself."